# backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read

Tags: python-2.7, apache-storm

I'm new to use python with storm . I'm facing problem with running it in Local Mode

```
ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:
usage: simbolt.py [-h] --data DATAPATH --pre PRECOMPPATH --res RESULT --inp
                  ORIGFILE
simbolt.py: error: argument --data/-d is required
```

I couldn't figure how can i fix it or where is the problem ?
If you need anything i can share it from code to know the reason please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what are you trying to do? If you are calling a sub-process I assume you are trying to run an external program from a bolt using data received in an incoming tuple? If so there are more Storm (JVM) native ways to do this, but would require using Java.

If you are processing data with Python plus other external programs and want to do it in a distributed way, Storm may not be your best bet. You may be better off using something like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

However, if you want all the advantages of Storm and you can rewrite whatever the external sub-process is doing in Python, then [StreamParse](http://streamparse.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) may be a good option.

If you can provide more information on what you are trying to do with the subprocess and your Topology overall I may be able to help further.

Comment: firstly . Many thanks for replying . can i get your email, please ?

Comment: @user5520049 I would rather not. Can't you update your post with a simplified example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: ok no problem , i'll edit it now . firstly . the error is disappeared after i deleted some import library in the bolt . but the process which i need to execute didn't be done . i will edit the post with the updates